# Caret preProcess = "medianImpute" yet still missing values error

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm fitting a model using caret and I have some missing data. I recall once before passing a argument to train "preProcess = "medianImpute" however I am receiving an unexpected error:

```
library(caret)
x <- mtcars
x[1:5, "cyl"] <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)

mod.mt <- train(
  mpg ~.,
  method = "rpart", # decision tree
  tuneLength = 3,
  preProcess = "medianImpute",
  data = x)
```

Gives:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1,  : 
  missing values in object
```

Because I was using preProcess I thought I was telling caret to use median impute for any missing values. So this error was unexpected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pre-processing code is only designed to work when x is a simple matrix or data frame. Basicly doesn't work when using train with a formula interface.

Code below works. Or first do `preProces`, `predict` and then `train` (2nd part of code).

```
mod.mt <- train(
  x = x[,2:10],
  y = x$mpg,
  method = "rpart", # decision tree
  tuneLength = 3,
  preProcess = "medianImpute"
  )

# first impute / predict 
d <- preProcess(x, "medianImpute")
x1 <- predict(d, x)

mod.mt <- train(
  mpg ~.,
   data = x1,
  method = "rpart", # decision tree
  tuneLength = 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "formula-style" train rather than the "matrix-style", you need to specify `na.action`. With imputation, usually you want to set it as `na.action = na.pass`, like this:

```
model_formula <-
  train(
    Class ~ .,
    data = train_data,
    na.action = na.pass,
    method = "glmnet",
    preProcess = "medianImpute",
    trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
  )
```

An alternative is setting `na.action = na.omit`, in which case, any observations with missing values will be filter out before the actual training, and imputation won't have a chance to kick in. In fact, if both `na.action = na.omit` and imputation exist, you will get a warning.

For more information, I suggest you look at the source code:

- This is why in your example you get an error (by default `na.action = na.fail`): https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/58b67424ad9cf782b05fb48188bdf7dd5bcf1ad4/pkg/caret/R/train.default.R#L946
- This is where imputation is actually performed in each resample loop: https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/58b67424ad9cf782b05fb48188bdf7dd5bcf1ad4/pkg/caret/R/createModel.R#L33